# Trouble using a loop to add characters to an array of "strings" in c?

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

So i tried this both with the datatype char and then the data type int. Nomatter what the printf shows only the first letter of the inputted word. For example if someone inputs dog it will just say 'd'.
My guess is maybe the syntax of word[i] only takes the first letter but im not sure how to fix that.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #define pause system("pause")
    #define cls system("cls")


void getUserWords(int *counter, int words[]){
            int i;

            printf("How many words would you like to enter into the cross word puzzle\n");
            scanf("%i",&*counter);
            for(i=0; i < *counter; i++){
                printf("Please enter word #%i\n",i+1);
                scanf("%s",&words[i]);
                printf("The word %c will be added to the crossword puzzle\n",words[i]);
                pause;
                cls;
            }//end for

            printf("Your all your words have been successfully added to the crossword puzzle");
            cls;
        }//end getUserWords
```

Comment: Why is `counter` a function parameter if 2 lines into the function you override it with the user's input anyway

Comment: im keeping a record of it to use again in another function :)

Comment: Ok - maybe it would be better to pass the count back to `main` through a return statement, so then in the main you could pass the return value of this function to the other function

Comment: @TimCastelijns "you override it with the user's input" -- that doesn't happen ... only the value counter points to is changed, not counter itself. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with this approach (except that it should be called counterp, not counter), although returning the counter value is cleaner than passing in a pointer to it (unless there are multiple return values).

Comment: @JimBalter `only the value counter points to is changed` that is what i meant to say. I thought he wanted to pass a value for counter as parameter, i didnt know it was solely to keep track of it to reuse it later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read your C library documentation relating to printf() and friends,
you would remember that "%c" is the format string for single characters. If
you want to print a string up to a terminating NULL, you should use "%s".

You have:

```
 printf("The word %c will be added to the crossword puzzle\n",words[i]);
```

But you should have

```
 printf("The word %s will be added to the crossword puzzle\n",words[i]);
```

Also, make sure that your second arg to the function has enough space allocated to store `counter` words.

Comment: Thank you thank makes sense! Its crashes with errors when i use s, how do i make sure enough space is allocated?

Comment: for starters declare your words array as an array of strings `char* words[]` instead of ints

Comment: Still it wont work..as you using a 1D array and assigning value to just a `single position`(1 byte for char) by using `words[i]`..You need to use either a `2D array` or `%s in scanf as words` and not words[i]...

Comment: Um, this answer is no good because it doesn't address the type of `words` ... you're printing an int with %s

Comment: @jim-balter If you give all the answers right away, how will the OP learn the craft of C ?

Comment: Maybe you should read the FAQ and learn what is expected of answers here. And what's this "right away" crap? You have had plenty of time to improve your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`int words[]` words is an array of integers which can hold only ints of specified size. 
Now when you use, `scanf("%s",&words[i]);` you're are trying to read a string into just a each integer location which is in-correct. Thats the reasons you are able to store only first character even though you enter a string.

Comment: ..... which also means that words[] should be declared as char*, and calloc'd prior to calling your function via

`words = calloc(counter * sizeof(char));`

You should also figure out how many words you want to hold, and how long they might be, so that you get `counter` correct. Might just be easier to assert that you'll only accept `n` words, up to 80 chars (std line length), and then allocate via

     words = calloc(n * 80 * sizeof(char))

Comment: alright im going to change everything to char and try that to figure it out thanks